# Downloaded an Audio file into File Manager need to play it from local path

Tags: ios, swift, download, nsfilemanager

I am working in an audio player application, and also I am having a offline download option, when the user click the download button it should start download and save it into local. I have saved it using file manager URLSession.

I have tried of taking and separating the destination url. I am using a jukebox third party for playing the song. the sample file location is

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BBB9AF1C-D87C-4C40-9F29-AD89062A20E2/Documents/05-KARMA-YOGA.mp3

```
if let audioUrl = URL(string: audioTobedownloaded) {
            // then lets create your document folder url
            let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            // lets create your destination file url
            let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
            print(destinationUrl)
```

the actual thing is how should I play the audio which I have downloaded in file manager.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer has a function that you can pass the filepath to

Answer (score 0):

```
func findFilesWith(extensionType: String) -> [URL]{
        var matches = [URL]()
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let files = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
        // *** this section here adds all files with the chosen extension to an array ***
        for item in files!
        {
            let fileURL = item as! URL

            if (fileURL.pathExtension == extensionType)
            {
                matches.append(fileURL)
            }
        }
        return matches
    }
```

You can use this method to get all kinds of file with respective to the extension type.

In your case use mp3 as extension type

Try the below method to play audio from the fetched url

```
func play(url:URL) {
        print("playing \(url)")

        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.volume = 1.0
            player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } catch {
            print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
        }

    }
```